# How get text lines larger than 69cm?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I’m using Apache OpenOffice 4.1.6 and I want to convert a text file to ᴘᴅꜰ without automatic line returns.

In practice this requires using very wide page sizes.

I enabled landscape mode set page as wide as 300cm. But even with a negative margin, I’m still getting automatic line breaks at about 69cm which is far beind the size allowed by the margin and the page as seen on the image below where the text don’t continue on the same line even without a line break.[image]
What setting I need to change in order to use full page size (at least 150cm) if it’s not margin nor page size ?

Comment: Affects also Libreoffice (6.0.6.2) on Linux, so i've removed the Win10 tag and added LO.